# useEffect cleanup never called when using Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using Electron with React JS to build my app, and using `useEffect` to listen from events of `ipcRenderer`. The problem is that, for some reason, the  useEffect subscribe is being called twice, and every time I reload the Electron window using cmd+R its subscribes again, and the `useEffect` cleanup is never called, so it starts stacking ipcRender subscriptions. My code is the following:

App.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NetworkRequest, networkRequest } from './models/request';
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');

const Home = () => {
  const homeState = useHomeState()
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Requests</h1>
      {/* Here i'll have a list with homeState.requests */}
    </>
  )
}

class InitialHomeState {
  requests: NetworkRequest[]

  constructor(requests: NetworkRequest[]) {
    this.requests = requests
  }
}

const useHomeState = () => {
  const [homeState, setHomeState] = useState(new InitialHomeState([]))
  useEffect(() => {
    function proxyRequestHandler(requestPayload: any) {
      setHomeState(state => {
        const newRequest = new NetworkRequest(requestPayload.hostname, requestPayload.url, networkRequest(requestPayload.method))
        const requests = state.requests
        requests.push(newRequest)
        return { ...state, requests }
      })
    } 
    console.log("SUBSCRIBING")
    ipcRenderer.on('proxy-new-request', (evt: any, payload: any) => {
      console.log(evt)
      proxyRequestHandler(payload)
    })

    return function unsubscribeProxyListener() {
      console.log("UNSUBSCRIBING")
      ipcRenderer.removeListener('proxy-new-request', proxyRequestHandler)
    }
  }, [])

  return homeState
}

const App = () => <Home/>

export default App
```

index.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and Electron main.ts

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const hoxy = require('hoxy')
const fs = require('fs')

var proxy = hoxy.createServer({
    certAuthority: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/my-private-root-ca.key.pem`),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/my-private-root-ca.crt.pem`)
      }
}).listen(8080);

app.on('ready', () => {

    this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }})
    this.mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/')
    this.mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    this.mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        proxy.intercept('request', (req, res, cycle) => {
            this.mainWindow.webContents.send('proxy-new-request', { headers: req.headers, protocol: req.protocol, hostname: req.hostname, method: req.method, url: req.url });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You need to find out why the useEffect subscribe is called twice, I don't see anything wrong from above code. Perhaps you're using `nodemon` or other livereloader,  problem might be there.

Comment: As of why the unsubscribe logic is not called, I think it's because you hard refresh the page. And the "unmount" phase of react is simply bypassed. React is design for normal browser, in that context bypassing unmount on window close is fine. But for electron this cause trouble. You'll need to customize `useEffect` to also force run unsub logic on `window. onbeforeunload ` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a thanks to @hackape which open my way to the following solution.

For those facing the same issue, I resolved doing the following:

1. Use a bool var on main electron file to avoid double proxy listener setup

```js
if (!didSetupListener) {
            didSetupListener = true
            proxyServer.on('new-request', (request: NetworkRequest) => {
                mainWindow.webContents.send('proxy-new-request', request)
            })
        }
```

2. On React `useEffect()`, check if it's not already subscribed

```js
if (ipcRenderer.rawListeners('proxy-new-request').length === 0) {
      ipcRenderer.on('proxy-new-request', (evt: any, request: NetworkRequest) => {
        proxyRequestHandler(request)
      })
    }
```

OBS: This is probably not the right way of doing it, but at least it helped me keep using CMD+R while developing.